# Dnx AuthenticationMiddleware not going to next middleware if successful

Tags: asp.net, authentication, basic-authentication, dnx

I am having an issue with my [BasicAuth Project](https://github.com/Gekctek/BasicAuth) for dnx451 and dnx50 in Aspnet5. I am attempting to use the models from Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication (such as AuthenticationHandler and AuthenticationMiddleware) but am failing to understand some of the fundamentals. Currently my issue is that when my BasicAuth middleware gets called it runs but after even a successful authentication it does not continue to the next middleware.

Things that would help me better debug understand this:

- Is the auth middleware designed to continue to the next middleware after completion?
- Where does the 'already authenticated, no need to auth again' get checked? Should that be in my code or does the middleware not get called if already authenticated?
- Is this specific middleware not designed to be used for something like basic auth where the credentials are sent for every request?

Any information on this specific implementation would be helpful.

Comment: Did you read the this document http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html Examples are also available on https://github.com/aspnet/Security. It seems that resume to the next middleware

Comment: I did not know about the aspnet 5 documentation. That is helpful to have. But it doesn't seem to have anything about creating a custom auth middleware. I have looked at the other source codes for auth middleware and i cant find any clarity on what I am doing wrong. But ill keep looking. Thanks